# Cant Open Ubuntu after installing windows 8

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I do not have much experience with the inside workings of Windows or Ubuntu but this is my problem.  I updated my Windows to Windows 8 on my computer which was previously running Ubuntu and Windows Vista. I had a GRUB launcher on there so I could open either Windows or Ubuntu after I had started the computer,  but after installing the Windows version my GRUB launcher was not there when I booted up the computer.  How do I get GRUB (or equivalent) back? I am stuck on the Windows side so an answer to install from the Ubuntu side will likely no work. I do not have the disc for Ubuntu.

Comment: Try with this solution and let us know your result: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Answer (score 0):

EasyBCD is a windows software which allows you to choose Ubuntu on startup.
Try the below steps to `install/Configure` EasyBCD and get back to your ubuntu os without data loss.

- Log in into your windows 8 os.Download and install EasyBCD from [*`here`*.](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/EasyBCD-Download-45820.html)
- Open the EasyBCD software.Under linux section select `grub 2` as bootloader and choose appropriate Ubuntu Partition to add boot entry for Ubuntu os.
  And also add entry for your windows 8 os by selecting appropriate windows 8 partition.
- reboot

Now there was an option to choose whether windows or ubuntu on startup.